# Can I force MSTest to use a new process for each test run?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, pinvoke, mstest

We're using the VS 2010 test runner (MSTest) for automated functional testing. When we run tests from Visual Studio, VS creates a process called QTAgent32.exe, and it runs the tests in that process.

We've found that when we do multiple test runs, MSTest will reuse the same QTAgent32 process - the process ID does not change. This is a problem for us, since the code we're testing is P/Invoking to an unmanaged DLL. The DLL needs to be initialized only once during the lifetime of the process. We have an [AssemblyInitialize] method, but that executes once per test run. If we perform multiple test runs, it will execute more than once in the same process.

Every time we do a test run, MSTest creates a new appdomain; but these appdomains are all in the same process.

So I'm wondering: is there a way to tell the Visual Studio test runner to use a new process every time we run tests? I looked at the ".testsettings" configuration but didn't see anything relevant.

Comment: Just for my curiosity - is it possible that the unmanaged DLL is unloaded after each consecutive test with `FreeLibrary`?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - good suggestion. Right now the code just statically references the unmanaged APIs, using [DllImport] attributes on C# extern function declarations. I assume .NET doesn't automatically free the library when the appdomain is torn down, since we are getting errors. I don't actually know how to call a dynamically-loaded DLL from C# code - can you call LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress(), and then somehow cast the returned function pointer to a delegate type? Anyway, I'll look into it - thanks! I just found this which may help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dyninvok.aspx

Comment: I have some C++ code I'm testing and I can confirm that MSTest does *not* unload DLLs between tests. It also does not call global variable destructors, so that makes me think it's the same executable the whole time.

Answer (score 6):

dont know how far you want to go with it, but one solution could be to create your unit test host

http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/query/bb166558

this link shows how to create adapters, also you could then launch a new process for evertest, create a piped communication and tear it down after the test.

I know MS itself uses a different host for running tests under moles

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molestutorial.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out. I didn't realize you could create a custom host. Right now we're looking to see if there is a different test runner (e.g. Gallio Icarus) which can run the tests in a new process each time. It's really only an issue while interactively developing and testing - on the build server, we have just a single test run in a single test process.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working after reading Wiktor's comment about FreeLibrary().

I used [this class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/06/typesafe-getprocaddress.aspx) created by Mike Stall, which provides wrappers around LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, and FreeLibrary. That way, I can load the library once in each test run, call the necessary methods, and then free the library at the end of the test run.

Mike Stall's code uses [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx), which converts an unmanaged function pointer to a managed delegate type.

I had to replace the [DllImport] extern declarations with declarations for delegate types. So I converted this:

```
[DllImport("asesignal.dll")]
public static extern bool ASESDK_Initialize(string licenseCode);
```

to this:

```
public delegate bool ASESDK_Initialize(string licenseCode);
```

Mike Stall's code contained examples with generic delegates (Action<T> etc.). But I couldn't get that working, so I created my own delegate types.

I can load the DLL dynamically like this:

```
_ht = new UnmanagedLibrary(@"c:\windows\system32\asesignal.dll");
```

To call a function, I do this:

```
var function = _ht.GetUnmanagedFunction<ASESDK_Initialize>("ASESDK_Initialize");
function(licenseCode);
```

Thanks Wiktor and np-hard for your help!

Answer (score 0):

VS 2013 and forward now has a setting for this under Test > Test Settings > Keep Test Execution Engine Running. Unchecking this selection will start up a new engine each run.

Comment: This did not seem to have an effect, it's still running all the tests in the same process for me in Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

I created an (experimental) solution for MSTest + .Net Core in 2023

It requires https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tmds.ExecFunction

```
public class OutOfProcessTestAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
    private static readonly FunctionExecutor Executor = new FunctionExecutor(
    o =>
    {
        o.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        o.OnExit = p =>
        {
            if (p.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
            }
        };
    });

    public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
    {
        var hostFilename = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;

        if (hostFilename.EndsWith("/testhost") || hostFilename.EndsWith("\\testhost.exe"))
        {
            return base.Execute(testMethod);
        }

        try
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(testMethod.MethodInfo.DeclaringType!);
            Action action = (Action)testMethod.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), obj);
            Executor.Run(action);
            return new TestResult[1] { new() { Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Passed } };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new TestResult[1] { new() { TestFailureException = e, Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Failed } };
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can replace `[TestMethod]` with `[OutOfProcessTest]`

Important things to note:

1. It will create a new instance of the Test Class, because I couldn't get reference to the original instance. Therefor try to make the method self contained as possible, the `[TestInitialize]` etc attributes won't apply.
2. When running inside Visual Studio Test Host, `Tmds.ExecFunction` does not work because it cannot find the parent process (works fine from `dotnet test` though). I choose to just run the test normally, but you should modify the attribute to behave as you want (e.g. perhaps skip the test instead of run it)
3. I did not test `async` functions, perhaps it will require some modification to support.